# How to synchronize table headers with their content?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, html-table

I need to ensure that the table columns align with their respective headers. Given an array of headers as follows:

```js
const titles = ['name', 'lastname', 'age']
```

when rendering the table, the content, which may look as follows:

```js
const content = ['lastnameText', 15, 'nameText']
```

should adjust to match the corresponding headers.

The challenge here is that the order of items in the content array may not match the order of headers.

```js
<table>
  <thead>
    {titles.map(item => (
      <tr>{item}</tr>
    ))}
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {content.map(item => (
      <tr>{item}</tr>
    ))}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Currently, the result appears as follows:

```js
   name       lastname     age
lastnametext     15      nametext
```

As you can see, the header columns are not correctly positioned. The desired outcome should look as follows:

```js
   name      lastname     age
 nameText  lastnametext   15
```

Comment: You should think about changing the structure of your data, maybe an array of objects like `[{name: name, age: 15, lastname: lastnametext}]`

Comment: ☝ tbh, with the structure you have it's highly impossible to know what value should go under the columns ...

Comment: The problem is that the headers must have a specified order. If you render according to the keys of the array, then, depending on their order, the headers will not be in the order that is necessary

Comment: The headers can stay in their structure, however change the *data* structure to an array of objects where each field has the matching header as its key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited this answer and found a solution for what you want. See this [code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-7qzhfz?file=src%2FApp.js,src%2FTable.js,src%2Findex.js).

***Note:** If all the rows fields in your `content` are in matching order, and just the headers order is the problem - **then this [code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-tqzqca?file=src%2FApp.js,src%2Findex.js) is enough.**

---

So in order to make it work as a **re-useable** table, and work even if the `content` order is **messed up** -   what I do is simply sorting the `content` I get before displaying it:

```
  const allSortedContent = []; 

  for (const row in props.content) {
    const sortedRowValues = []; 
    // Pushing the values of this row to the `sortedValues` according the order of the headers.
    props.headers.forEach((header) => {
      const value = props.content[row][header];
      sortedRowValues.push(<td>{value}</td>);
    });
    allSortedContent.push(<tr>{sortedRowValues}</tr>);
  }
```

Here I go through the `content` array which contains rows as objects.
For each row - I sort the fields of it to be according the order of the headers. In each iteration, I use the `sortedRowValues` array that will contain the `<td>` elements of this row (matching the order of the headers).

After finishing each row, I push the mapped row - (*`sortedRowValues`*) to the `allSortedContent` array which contains all the sorted rows.

Lastly, in the table body, I simply return the `allSortedContent`.

```
return (
    <div>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            {props.headers.map((item) => (
              <td>{item}</td>
            ))}
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>{allSortedContent}</tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
```

And the data structure you send through `props` should be in this structure, but it's completely okay if it's out of order:

```
const headers = ['age', 'lastName', 'name'];

const content = [
    { name: 'Jule', lastName: 'Abc', age: '24' },
    { lastName: 'Park', age: '32', name: 'Josh' },
  ];
```

Comment: if the order of the headers looks like this: ['age', 'name', 'lastname']? What then

Comment: Now I am writing exactly as you showed, the issue is not solved

Comment: Change the place of age with name in headers, the content is still out of sync from headers

Comment: Of course it will be because you changed the place of the header, so you need to change the order of how you want to show the `<td/>` elementes in the second map to  match this too.

Comment: the table is a reusable component, I can't create a separate table for each array to be able to change the order of the data in the body

Comment: I need the table to render the data in the order that they are set in the headers

Comment: Edited the answer. I hope the result is what you where expecting.

Comment: Note: If all the rows fields in your content are in matching order, and just the headers order is the problem - then this [code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-tqzqca?file=src%2FApp.js,src%2Findex.js) is enough.

Answer (score 1):

i think it'll solve your problem because you have a array and you want to write keys in head and write items in body. I assumed like this.

```
<table>
  <thead>
    {Object.keys(contents).map((key) => {
        <tr>{key}</tr>
    })}
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {contents.map(item => (
      <tr>{item}</tr>
    ))}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Or maybe you have a just sort problem. I don't know what you have done.